max length is not working angular 2 plus version
I am working on an application where I am implementing max length but it is not working. below is my implementation

TS

   this.customPaymentForm = new FormGroup({
            amount: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/)]),
            cVVCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(4)),
        })


HTML

<div class="input">
        <label for="">Cryptogramme visuel <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="cVVCode" placeholder="XXXX" />
        <div class="text-error" *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode').errors && (customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode').touched || customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode').hasError('required')">Cryptogramme visuel est requis.</div>
            <div *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode').hasError('maxlength')">Cryptogramme visuel doit avoir au maximum 4 caractères.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

It doesn't show an error message.

Please provide a stackblitz repro, this should work.

Since the input field is of type number, you should use max validator, which checks the maximum possible number of 4 characters (9999).
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="customPaymentForm">
      <div class="input">
          <label for="">Cryptogramme visuel <span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="cVVCode" placeholder="XXXX" />
          {{customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.errors | json}} | 
          <div class="text-error" *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.errors && (customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.touched || customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.dirty)">
              <div *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.hasError('required')">Cryptogramme visuel est requis.</div>
              <div *ngIf="customPaymentForm.get('cVVCode')?.hasError('max')">Cryptogramme visuel doit avoir au maximum 4 caractères.</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  customPaymentForm = new FormGroup<any>({});
  ngOnInit() {
    this.customPaymentForm = new FormGroup<any>({
      amount: new FormControl(0, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/),
      ]),
      cVVCode: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.max(9999),
      ]),
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
